# How to configure streamlit to serve an app to www?

Tags: web-server, web-applications, websocket, wss, tornado

streamlit app is running in a centOS stream 8 virtual machine. Access from intranet is fine but fails with "streamlit please wait.. page" when accessed from www via subDomain.companyDomain.com

Tested R shiny app and a static page from same virtual machine and same port. Both are successfully accessible from www with subDomain.companyDomain.com

network schema [image: network schema]

**subDomain != virtualMachineName**

**company proxy server is ssl enabled**

streamlit config.toml

```
[server]
port = 8585
headless = true
enableCORS = false
enableXsrfProtection = false
enableWebsocketCompression = false
address = "0.0.0.0"

[browser]
gatherUsageStats = false
serverAddress = "subDomain.companyDomain.com"
```

**Edit 1:**

tested Apache reverse proxy

`/etc/httpd/conf.d/testApp.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subDomain.companyDomain.com
    ServerAlias www.subDomain.companyDomain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/" "http://local_IP:8585/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://local_IP:8585/"
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/testApp-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/testApp-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Interestingly, after redirecting `http:local_IP:8585` to Apache virtualHost `*:80`, both `local_IP:80` and subDomain.companyDomain.com hang at the same "streamlit.. please wait" page.

(btw, httpd/testApp* log files are empty)

**Edit 2**

With nginx (this [thread](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/streamlit-docker-nginx-ssl-https/2195)), both `http://local_IP:8585` and `http://local_IP:80` correctly display the app. However, subDomain.companyDomain.com continues to hang with "streamlit please wait" page.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://local_IP:8585/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    }
}
```

browser trace suggests error in redirection to/from company proxy server via **websocket**. But i can not pin point where and how to resolve error.

**Edit 3**
Tracing browser request via DevTools

[image]
[image]

```
ss -tulpn |grep "streamlit"
tcp LISTEN 0 128 0.0.0.0:8585 0.0.0.0:* users:(("streamlit",pid=206126,fd=8)) 

netstat -tulpn
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:8585 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 206126/python
tcp6 0 0 :::8585 :::* LISTEN 206126/python
```

Cross posted in [streamlit.io](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/how-to-configure-streamlit-to-serve-an-app-to-www/42079) because i am not sure if this problem is caused by streamlit or server.

Comment: - Are there any records in log files (streamlit | python | /var/log ) ?  
- How about to monitor network activity by  ss or netstat  command to specify source of the issue

Comment: streamlit logs has no info related to failed app rendering from www. (I guess apps are running fine from the local ip, therefore perhaps streamlit is not showing up any errors in log ?!)

Comment: It is good to check whether and in which form streamlit server receives requests. In which state are sockets (ports) for incoming connections during web request. The commands `ss -tulpn` or `netstat -tulpn | grep streamlit` can give listeneng ports with originating ip (suppose thae application name is as indicated).  On the other end -- what shows the trace browser's request via _Development tools_?

Comment: @TomNewton: edited question to include output of `ss -tulpn` and browser request trace

Comment: it seems, next step will be solving https://www.google.com/search?q=a+websocket+connection+error+occurred  Sorry, I'm not deeply familiar with web-programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is related to web socket blocked by company server.